# wc_add_notice working randomly in WooCommerce add to cart validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dokan

So I'm making some custom code to Allow specific producut purchase based on points accumulated from WooCommerce's points and rewards plugin, when checking the points balance, I'm using wc_add_notice to display the error if their balance is not enough.
It worked the first time, then I can no longer get those notices, I tried executing it in multiple different ways, nothing seems to work !

Here's my code :

```
function enforce_points_based_registration( $valid, $product_id ) {

    if ( $product_id == 4465 ) {
        $points_required = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'points_required', true); 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_points = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::get_users_points( $user_id );
        $current_user= wp_get_current_user();
        $user_email = $current_user->email;

        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $user_email, $user_id, $product_id )) {
            $message = "You have already bought the Vendor package";
            wc_add_notice( apply_filters('wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id), "error");
            return false;
        }
        
        if ( dokan_is_user_vendor( $user_id) ) {
            $message = "You are already a vendor.";
            wc_add_notice( apply_filters('wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id), "error");
            return false;
        }
        
        if ( $user_points < $points_required ) {

            // User doesn't have enough points, prevent purchase
            $message = "You don't have enough points to purchase the subscription";
            wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ),  "error" );

            return false;
        } else {

            // User has enough points, place the order
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            $order = wc_create_order();
            $order->add_product( $product, 1 );
            $order->set_customer_id( $user_id );
            $order->calculate_totals();
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );

            // Deduct points
            WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::decrease_points( $user_id, $points_required, 'vendor_registration', $order->get_id() );

 
            // Add custom message to the order notes
            $order->add_order_note( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', "The order was automatically placed and paid for using points.", $product_id ) );
            
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'enforce_points_based_registration', 10, 2 );
```

I tried calling it that way with apply_filters, which worked the first time, I also tried wc_add_notice($message,$type) still nothing seems to work, although most of the code works as expected.

The code is placed in functions.php ( Child theme )

Answer (score 0):

The filter hook `wc_add_to_cart_message` doesn't exist in WooCommerce, so you should remove it from all wc_add_notice() functions in your code, as it can be the source of your issue, and doesn't provide anything useful.

I have revised your code, try the following:

```php
function enforce_points_based_registration( $passed, $product_id ) {
    global $current_user;

    if ( $product_id != 4465 ) 
        return $passed;

    $points_required = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'points_required', true); 
    $user_points     = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::get_users_points( $current_user->ID );

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->email, $current_user->ID, $product_id )) {
        wc_add_notice( __("You have already bought the Vendor package", "woocommerce"), "error");
        $passed = false;
    } 
    elseif ( dokan_is_user_vendor( $current_user->ID) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __("You are already a vendor", "woocommerce"), "error");
        $passed = false;
    } 
    elseif ( $user_points < $points_required ) {
        // User doesn't have enough points, prevent purchase
        wc_add_notice( __("You don't have enough points to purchase the subscription", "woocommerce"),  "error" );
        $passed = false;
    } 
    else {
        // User has enough points, place the order
        $order = wc_create_order();
        $order->add_product( wc_get_product( $product_id ), 1 );
        $order->set_customer_id($current_user->ID);
        $order->calculate_totals();
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );

        // Deduct points
        WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::decrease_points( $current_user->ID, $points_required, 'vendor_registration', $order->get_id() );
 
        // Add custom message to the order notes
        $order->add_order_note( __("The order was automatically placed and paid with user's points.", "woocommerce") );
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'enforce_points_based_registration', 10, 2 );
```

It may work now.

Comment: I will try this and let you know ! The weird thing is that with that wc_add_to_cart_message it actually worked the first time, I'll update when I test it

Comment: It did not work, although everything else works perfectly, after clicking on the Buy Now button , it instantly refreshes the page could that be the issue as to why the notices don't show?

Comment: It seems that there are something else making trouble, It can be some other customizations made by you, your theme or a plugin.